# Add Search to tvOS UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, tvos, uisearchcontroller

I have a TableView with over 400 objects on my tvOS app, and it really needs to have search functionality on it.

After reading through some sample code from Apple, here is what I have.  SecondViewController is where the main TableView is, while I just kept the name of the resultsViewController the same as what Apple had it.  In the main one I have:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _resultsTableController = [[APLResultsTableController alloc] init];
    _searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:self.resultsTableController];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;

    // we want to be the delegate for our filtered table so didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called for both tables
    self.resultsTableController.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self; // so we can monitor text changes + others

    // Search is now just presenting a view controller. As such, normal view controller
    // presentation semantics apply. Namely that presentation will walk up the view controller
    // hierarchy until it finds the root view controller or one that defines a presentation context.
    //
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;  // know where you want UISearchController to be displayed

}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if (self.searchControllerWasActive) {
        self.searchController.active = self.searchControllerWasActive;
        _searchControllerWasActive = NO;

        if (self.searchControllerSearchFieldWasFirstResponder) {
            [self.searchController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
            _searchControllerSearchFieldWasFirstResponder = NO;
        }
    }
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];

    self.files  = [bundle pathsForResourcesOfType:@"pdf" inDirectory:@"AIMPDF"];
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [self.files objectAtIndex:thepath.row];

    self.title = @"Devo Songs";
    self.filenames = [[documentsDirectoryPath lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    NSLog(@"%@", filenames);

    if ([self savedSearchTerm])
    {
        //[[[self searchDisplayController] searchBar] setText:[self savedSearchTerm]];
    }
    NSMutableArray *names = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.files count]];
    for (NSString *path in self.files) {
        [names addObject:[[path lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension]];
    }
    self.files = names;


    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.parentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iphonebackground.png"]];
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *plan = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Plan Devo" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(picking)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = plan;


    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

}
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    // update the filtered array based on the search text
    NSString *searchText = searchController.searchBar.text;
    NSMutableArray *searchResults = [self.files mutableCopy];

    // strip out all the leading and trailing spaces
    NSString *strippedString = [searchText stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

    // break up the search terms (separated by spaces)
    NSArray *searchItems = nil;
    if (strippedString.length > 0) {
        searchItems = [strippedString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    }

    // build all the "AND" expressions for each value in the searchString
    //


    // hand over the filtered results to our search results table
    APLResultsTableController *tableController = (APLResultsTableController *)self.searchController.searchResultsController;
    tableController.filteredProducts = searchResults;
    [tableController.tableView reloadData];
}
- (void)handleSearchForTerm:(NSString *)searchTerm
{
    [self setSavedSearchTerm:searchTerm];

    if ([self searchResults] == nil)
    {
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [self setSearchResults:array];
        array = nil;
    }

    [[self searchResults] removeAllObjects];

    if ([[self savedSearchTerm] length] != 0)
    {
        for (NSString *currentString in [self files])
        {
            if ([currentString rangeOfString:searchTerm options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
            {
                [[self searchResults] addObject:currentString];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the Results View Controller, I have:

```
@implementation APLResultsTableController

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.filteredProducts.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *filename = [[[self.filteredProducts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSString *contentForThisRow = nil;


    contentForThisRow = filename;

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    [[cell textLabel] setText:contentForThisRow];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:90];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    return cell;

}


@end
```

I get the Search Bar added at the top of my main TableView, but nothing changes when I start typing in letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after an all-day event of me banging my head into a brick wall, I finally got it set up.  Just a note, I HATE how Apple's tutorial and Sample Code for this makes it overly complex.  They add in an NSObject of APLProducts, a BaseTableView, and make several compound NSPredicates inside their tutorial for making use of search in a TableView.  Could have been much simpler.

In the end, there were only 3 classes needed:

OriginalTableView
ResultsTableView
DetailsView

In OTV I declared property for SearchController and a NSMutableArray called searchResults.  All of my PDF files are in the directory AIMPDF.  I make the array based off of those files, remove extension for display.  It was in the Search Update part of the code that Apple got out of control with all the stuff they were trying to do.  Make it simple for a tutorial for goodness' sake.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _resultsTableController = [[APLResultsTableController alloc] init];
    _searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:self.resultsTableController];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;

    self.resultsTableController.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self; // so we can monitor text changes + others


    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;  // know where you want UISearchController to be displayed

}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if (self.searchControllerWasActive) {
        self.searchController.active = self.searchControllerWasActive;
        _searchControllerWasActive = NO;

        if (self.searchControllerSearchFieldWasFirstResponder) {
            [self.searchController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
            _searchControllerSearchFieldWasFirstResponder = NO;
        }
    }
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];

    self.files  = [bundle pathsForResourcesOfType:@"pdf" inDirectory:@"AIMPDF"];
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [self.files objectAtIndex:thepath.row];

    self.title = @"Devo Songs";
    self.filenames = [[documentsDirectoryPath lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    NSLog(@"%@", filenames);

    NSMutableArray *names = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.files count]];
    for (NSString *path in self.files) {
        [names addObject:[[path lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension]];
    }
    self.files = names;


    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.parentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iphonebackground.png"]];
    [super viewDidLoad];


    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

}
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    // update the filtered array based on the search text
    NSString *searchText = searchController.searchBar.text;
    NSMutableArray *searchResults2 = [self.files mutableCopy];

    // strip out all the leading and trailing spaces
    NSString *strippedString = [searchText stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

    // break up the search terms (separated by spaces)
    NSArray *searchItems = nil;
    if (strippedString.length > 0) {
        searchItems = [strippedString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    }



    for (NSString *searchString in searchItems) {

        NSPredicate *sPredicate =
        [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", searchString];
        [searchResults2 filterUsingPredicate:sPredicate];


    }


    // hand over the filtered results to our search results table
    APLResultsTableController *tableController = (APLResultsTableController *)self.searchController.searchResultsController;
    tableController.filteredProducts = searchResults2;
    [tableController.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)handleSearchForTerm:(NSString *)searchTerm
{
    [self setSavedSearchTerm:searchTerm];

    if ([self searchResults] == nil)
    {
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [self setSearchResults:array];
        array = nil;
    }

    [[self searchResults] removeAllObjects];

    if ([[self savedSearchTerm] length] != 0)
    {
        for (NSString *currentString in [self files])
        {
            if ([currentString rangeOfString:searchTerm options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
            {
                [[self searchResults] addObject:currentString];
            }
        }
    }
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSInteger rows;

        rows = [[self files] count];
    return rows;
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *filename = [[[self.files objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSString *contentForThisRow = nil;


        contentForThisRow = filename;

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


           [[cell textLabel] setText:contentForThisRow];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:90];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.selectedCountry = (tableView == self.tableView) ?
    self.files[indexPath.row] : self.resultsTableController.filteredProducts[indexPath.row];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowSong" sender:self];




}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowSong"])
    {

        NSLog(@"Selecting %@", self.selectedCountry);
        FirstViewController* userViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        userViewController.selectedCountry = self.selectedCountry;

        //if you need to pass data to the next controller do it here
    }
}
```

The ResultsTableView only needed this.  I probably needed less, but went overboard just in case.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.filteredProducts.count;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.selectedCountry = [self.filteredProducts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowSong" sender:self];




}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowSong"])
    {

        NSLog(@"SelectingSearch %@", self.selectedCountry);
        FirstViewController* userViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        userViewController.selectedCountry = self.selectedCountry;

        //if you need to pass data to the next controller do it here
    }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *filename = [[[self.filteredProducts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSString *contentForThisRow = nil;


    contentForThisRow = filename;

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    [[cell textLabel] setText:contentForThisRow];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:90];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    return cell;

}


@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Apple deprecated `UISearchDisplayController` in iOS 8, and removed it for iOS 9, which is why it's not available on tvOS.

You need to use [`UISearchController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchController/index.html), which you initialize and present in code.  Apple provides an example of how to do this in SearchViewController.swift, in the [UIKitCatalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/samplecode/UICatalogFortvOS/Introduction/Intro.html) tvOS sample code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of where to look.  I went to the sample code, read up, and tried implementing this.  I got the search bar to appear, but nothing is working as far as it changing view any.  I updated OP to show what I've tried.

Comment: Hi there, I'm sorry I tried to follow this but what is all this 
        
       self.searchControllerWasActive
        self.searchController.active = self.searchControllerWasActive;
        self.searchControllerWasActive = NO;
        
  self.searchControllerSearchFieldWasFirstResponder
            [self.searchController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
            _searchControllerSearchFieldWasFirstResponder = NO;

I assume they are BOOL on your .h but can't see another reference to them, would you mind explaining further.

Thanks for the info tho and I know the feeling of banging one